# Drop down - show previously selected in loop

Tags: php, sql

my problem is to show previously selected in a while loop. I found a way to do it in not-loop setup, but a loop is a problem for me.

The following code give me a drop down of countries (and country code):

```
<?php 

foreach($countries as $key => $value) { ?>

<option value="<?= $value . ' ' . $key ?>" title="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>

<?php } ?>
```

And it works good. But imagine someone edit their country, thus I would love to show previously selected country. Of course I have a variable with the specific previously selected country... Thanks.

Comment: Tip: `<?=` or `short_tags` is not always enabled. replace with `<?php echo` to ensure your code always works regardless of php.ini settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$preselected = 'whatever_previous_selected';

foreach($countries as $key => $value) { ?>

<option value="<?php $value; ?>" title="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>" <?php if($preselected == $value) {echo "selected='selected'"; }?>>
<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>
</option>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you all, I'm sure I'll find a way now. Generosity is extreme in this forum!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php 

foreach($countries as $key => $value) { ?>
 <?php if ($previousCountry == $value) ?>
    <option selected value="<?= $value . ' ' . $key ?>" title="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
 <?php else  ?>
    <option value="<?= $value . ' ' . $key ?>" title="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>>

<?php } ?>
```

Not sure with the syntax but you should detect if the value is equal to the previous country then you put **selected** attribute on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `selected='selected'` when you get id in edit.

```
<?php 
$id = 1; // In edit you get some value here
foreach($countries as $key => $value) { 
$selected = (isset($id) && $id == $key) ? "selected='selected'" : "";   
?>

<option value="<?= $value . ' ' . $key ?>" title="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>" <?php echo $selected ?>><?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 
$prevSelectedCountry;

foreach($countries as $key => $value) { ?>

<option <?php echo ($prevSelectedCountry == $value . ' ' . $key)?"selected='selected'":"" ?> value="<?= $value . ' ' . $key ?>" title="<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>

<?php } ?>
```